# Wordpress Registration with Email Confirmation

Tags: php, wordpress, registration

I have created a registration forms with PHP in my Wordpress site.
For now users can create an account and login normally.
But I want to add a function that sends an activation to email before they can login.

This is the current code I have.

```
    <?php
    $error= '';
    $success = '';
 
    global $wpdb, $PasswordHash, $current_user, $user_ID;
 
    if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'register' ) {
 
        $role_option = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['role-option']));
        $password1 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['password1']));
        $password2 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['password2']));
        $first_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['first_name']));
        $last_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['last_name']));
        $email = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['email']));
        $email2 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['email2']));
        $username = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['username']));
        $userrole = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['userrole']));

        
        if( $email == "" || $password1 == "" || $password2 == "" || $username == "" || $first_name == "" || $last_name == ""  || $role_option == "") {
            $error= 'Please don\'t leave the required fields.';
        } else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error= 'Invalid email address.';
        } else if(email_exists($email) ) {
            $error= 'Email already exist.';
        } else if($email <> $email2 ){
            $error= 'Emails do not match.'; 
        } else if($password1 <> $password2 ){
            $error= 'Password do not match.';       
        } else {
 
            $user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('first_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name), 'last_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $last_name), 'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $password1), 'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_role', $role_option)) );
            if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
                $error= 'Error on user creation.';
            } else {
                do_action('user_register', $user_id);
                $current_url = home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                wp_redirect( $current_url );
                exit;
                $success = 'You\'re successfully register';
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: So what did you already try regarding sending the email to the user? The code you've posted just shows the process of the registration but no signs of an attempt to send a email.

Comment: I know we can easily send and email with wp_mail or wp_new_user_notification. 
But I'm lost on the validation step, where they need some kind of activation key ?

Comment: Just add one user meta field like `user_verfication = 0` while register. after verification change this value to 1.